# If Else, Awk NR: How to remove a section header of table where there are no entries

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, files, grep

I am trying to summarise a table of data that changes everyday. I have already summarised the table to only display rows with entries that are larger than 30.

However, on some days, there are no entries more than 30 in the original table. When that happens, i do not need the entire section that is empty in the summary. How do i then remove the entire header for those sections?

Ideally, if there are no entries in all 5 sections, there should not be any lines printed ( or just a string that says: "None: there is no entry larger than 30" as i was trying to do)

Example of a summarised table with 5 sections, summarised_output.txt:

```
=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun      

Counter Name                                06/04 18:00     06/04 17:00     06/04 16:00     06/04 15:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45


=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun     

Counter Name                                06/05 14:00     06/05 13:00     06/05 12:00     06/05 11:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45


=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun      

Counter Name                                06/05 10:00     06/05 09:00     06/05 08:00     06/05 07:00
=========================================================================================================


=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun    

Counter Name                                06/05 06:00     06/05 05:00     06/05 04:00     06/05 03:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45


=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun      

Counter Name                                06/04 18:00     06/04 17:00     06/04 16:00     06/04 15:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45


=========================================================================================================
```

As you can see, the third section is empty because there is no entry in the original_output.txt file higher than 30. But the header is still there.

My summary code( worked):

```
awk '$1=="Month:"||$1==""||$1=="Counter"||(index($1, "=")!=0)||$3>=30|| $4>=30 || $5>=30||$6>=30' original_output.txt>>summarised_output.txt
```

My attempt at deleting the header (doesn't work):

```
touch summarised_output_temp.txt
awk '{if ($1=="Month:"||$1==""||$1=="Counter"||(index($1, "=")!=0)||$3>=30|| $4>=30 || $5>=30||$6>=30) print $0}' original_output.txt >> summarised_output_temp.txt
if (((wc -l < summarised_output_temp.txt)==42))
then
echo "None: there is no entry larger than 30" >> summarised_output.txt
else
cat output_7_temp.txt>>summarised_output.txt
fi
```

The error received for the attempt:

```
line 3: ((: (wc -l output_7_temp.txt | awk {print $1})==42: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt | awk {print $1})==42")
```

Comment: My gawk version is gawk 3.1.8

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have GNU `awk`, You could this script:

```
awk -v RS='={105}[^=]*={105}' 'NF{print oRT,$0} {oRT=RT}' file
```

The table header is set as a multiline record separator `RS`. It is composed of twice 105 `=` characters with anything inbetween.

The variable `RT` is catching the record separtor for each record, and is stored in the variable `oRT` and printed at the next record provided that there is some elements to print (which is catch with `NF`).

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help! I am receiving error for this: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
. I guess i might not have GNU awk, but i'm not sure. i checked man awk but i didn't find anything

Comment: @tthhss Try using `gawk` instead of `awk`. You can also figure out the version you're using with the command `awk --version`.

Comment: gawk worked, but there is no change in the output file. The headers still appeared for empty sections. perhaps there can be a if else way using a temporary file? I was thinkin of using grep, but couldn't figure a way to include the header if i searched for "SYS.SYS"

Comment: I'm using `GNU awk 4.2.1` and the header including the string `06/05 10:00` doesn't appear with this awk script.

Comment: oh thats exactly what im trying to do, my gawk version is 3.1.8. I will go look it up and see if there are similar command for this version

Comment: `gawk '{print RT}' RS='(=+\n\\S[^=]+){2}' ORS='' input.txt`. Another version. But it lose the last border line, too (equal characters).

Answer (score 1):

Create an executable script test.awk, containing

```
awk '
  # { print "read " $0 }
  /^SYS/ {
    if (H) {
      if (F) {print F} else { F="\r\n\r\n"}
      print H; H=""}
    print
    next
  }
  /^./ {
    H=$0
    for (i=1; i<5; i++) {
      getline
      H = H "\r\n" $0
    }
    next
  }
' $@
```

and run

```
test.awk original_output.txt
```

"/^SYS/ {"  can be replaced by anything that recognizes a data line.

Comment: Hi! so glad for your help. I dunno why but i tried running it and it returns : test.awk: Command not found.
I also added a first line "#!/usr/bin/awk" after doing "which awk", it didn't help.

Comment: What is the third word of my answer, in case you skipped that?

Comment: It works! May i ask what is the (i=1; i<5;i++) referring to? I presume it is the 4 lines of heading?

Comment: Almost, since there are 5 lines of heading. My script is very weak, only works when data lines always start with "SYS", and there are always exactly 5 header lines.  If you can come up with something better to recognize the data lines, I'll improve both.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be tackled with Perl along these lines.

**Code**

```
perl -F'/^=+$/m' -lan -0777e '
   my($dashes) = /^(=+)$/m;
   shift @F; pop @F;
   while ( @F > 1 ) {
      my($h, $s) = splice @F, 0, 2;
      next if $s =~ /^(?:\h*\n)+$/;
      print join $dashes, q(), $h, $s, !@F ? q() : ();
   }
' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun

Counter Name                                06/04 18:00     06/04 17:00     06/04 16:00     06/04 15:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45



=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun

Counter Name                                06/05 14:00     06/05 13:00     06/05 12:00     06/05 11:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45



=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun

Counter Name                                06/05 06:00     06/05 05:00     06/05 04:00     06/05 03:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45



=========================================================================================================
Month: Jun

Counter Name                                06/04 18:00     06/04 17:00     06/04 16:00     06/04 15:00
=========================================================================================================
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45
SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.SYS.                  : 45              45              45              45


=========================================================================================================
```

**Explanation**

- Slurp the input in one go:   **-0777** option to ***Perl*** enables that.
- Split this whole file (now being treated as one long string) along the dashes: **/^=+$/m** means wherever a given line comprises nothing but repeated equals is where we split the file on.
- **-a** option will make **perl** stuff the the split parts into the array **@F**.
- **-n** option to Perl will disable the autoprinting just before reading the next record AND also does a ***awk***-like looping on records read from input.
- First off we store the dashes line from the input.
- Note that the split operation will make  the first and last elements to be empty, hence we remove those from the **@F** array before undertaking the main task.
- We setup a while loop what consumes 2 elements (**splice**) at a time from the **@F** array.First is the header and second the section. The loop continues so long as there are at least 2 elements still in the array.
- The key point is in taking the decision to skip or not to skip processing the header/section duo. And that gets decided when the section comprises just empty lines or lines comprising only horizontal whitespace (**\h**). The regex for that is **/^(?:\h*\n)+$/**
- Now if the section isn't empty, there remains the task of stitching together the header/section duo with the dashes. We keep in mind that at the last header/section coming together we need to add the dashes to round off.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to oliv's answer, perhaps a little simpler:

```
gawk -v RS='=+\n' '
    NR % 2 == 0 {header = $0; next}
    /[^[:space:]]/ {printf "%s", RT header RT $0}
    END {print RT}
' output.txt
```

Using a line of `=`s as the record separator. The header is then every even numbered record. And the "contents" are not empty if it contains a non-whitespace character.

`RT` is a GNU awk specific variable containing "The input text that matched the text denoted by RS, the record separator. It is set every time a record is read."